Can Ubuntu 24.04 system volume not adjust the device volume of the Bluetooth speaker?
Recently, I upgraded my computer from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 24.04. Then I found that in Ubuntu 16.04, the Bluetooth speak(Google-Nest-mini) volume won't be adjusted by the Ubuntu system volume, they are two independent volumes.
After I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04, when I adjusted the Ubuntu system volume, it also adjusted the device volume of the Bluetooth speaker. It seems like they are integrated to only one volume.
How can I turn back to the two independent volumes just like in Ubuntu 16.04?
Thanks.
